# accelerometer log during sleep with android? which mobiles are able to do this?

Tags: android, accelerometer, sleep

There is a problem with getting the accelerometer data during sleep. even a partial wake will not work on any device.

I'm interested in knowing which mobiles this will work on? Or which firmwares.
Could it be that on android 2.1 this will work on any device? or on 1.7?

Answer (score 0):

check this if it helps
https://market.android.com/details?id=singh.pal.ajeet&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInNpbmdoLnBhbC5hamVldCJd